# Bluetooth class "Limited Discoverable Mode"

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth-device with class `20258C`. - It's a remote control. According to the [Class of Device (CoD) Calculator](http://www.ampedrftech.com/cod.htm) this means the device has the following attributes:

- Major Device Class: Peripheral
- Limited Discoverable Mode
- Audio
- Pointing device
- Remote control

My questions regard the **"Limited Discoverable Mode"**.

- What exactly does this mean?
- How can I connect such a device to another BT-device? Is it even possible if I have no MAC-Address? I only know "Supplier ID", "Product ID" and "Bluetooth device Name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "Limited Discoverable Mode" just means that its advertising only lasts for a limited amount of time, usually 30 seconds.

If you know the device name this should be enough to find it and possibly connect to it. Since it's a remote control, I'd try removing a/the battery and then put it back in to reset (power cycle) the Bluetooth radio. This should knowingly restart the advertising process (otherwise I'm not sure what would on the remote, maybe one of the buttons?).

Comment: Thank you! You post finally helped me to get this remote control working, because of the hint "remove the batteries"...  The "documentation" of the remote says how to get it into pairing mode (=pressing 2 buttons at the same time). But this NEVER worked. I found out, that I have to remove the batteries, put them back in and THEN press the 2 buttons. If you don't remove the batteries first, the pairing process will never work.